# How to correct spacing between `=` under the SUM sign when using breqn package?

Tags: spacing, typography, breqn

In this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}    
\newcommand{\myEquation}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n +5} a_{n} = \sum_{n=5}^{\infty}a_{n -5} x^{n} }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\myEquation
\end{equation}

\begin{dmath*}
\myEquation
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex under TL 2022 on Linux gives

[image]

The spacing is wrong under the summation sign when using `dmath` environment (from breqn  package). And this seems to happen with zero and not the `5`.

Is there a way to make the spacing same for `n=0` same as for the `n=5` ?

Comment: The output is also the same for pdflatex and XeLaTeX too.

Answer (score 3):

It's explained on page 9 of the manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n +5} a_{n} = \sum_{n=5}^{\infty}a_{n -5} x^{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{dmath*}
\sum_{n\hiderel{=}0}^{\infty} x^{n +5} a_{n} = \sum_{n=5}^{\infty}a_{n -5} x^{n}
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I told you several years ago that `breqn` solves almost nothing, if you want a *good* output.